# cannot access github.com

Tags: hosts, dig, nslookup

I cannot nslookup github:

```
nslookup github 8.8.8.8
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

nslookup github.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

nb: default ns server = gw = router 4g = 192.168.0.1 (a cache dns server I guess). I am on a 192.168.0.0/24, my ip = 192.168.0.130, bcast = 192.168.0.255, ip given by router via dhcp.

my nslookup seems to be working:

```
nslookup google.com 
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 142.250.187.206
Name:   google.com
Address: 2a00:1450:4009:81f::200e
```

I can tlslookup github.com

```
tlslookup github.com 
140.82.113.4
```

nb: I dont know why resolution works with this tool and not with nslookup. I tried to grab infos regarding tlslookup over google but nothing.

I check with dig (just in case my nslookup does not work fine). Unfortunately the pb remains with this tool.

```
dig github.com
; <<>> DiG 9.16.27-Debian <<>> github.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

dig @8.8.8.8 github.com
; <<>> DiG 9.16.27-Debian <<>> @8.8.8.8 github.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Obviously all commands relying on name resolution wont work, but for the sake of the post, I tried some of them:

```
ping $(tlslookup github.com)
PING 140.82.114.3 (140.82.114.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 140.82.114.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=259 ms
64 bytes from 140.82.114.3: icmp_seq=2 ttl=50 time=317 ms
64 bytes from 140.82.114.3: icmp_seq=3 ttl=50 time=238 ms
^C
--- 140.82.114.3 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 237.514/271.189/316.968/33.546 ms
```

but

```
ping github.com
ping: github.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
openssl s_client -connect github.com:443
140311527400768:error:2008F002:BIO routines:BIO_lookup_ex:system lib:../crypto/bio/b_addr.c:730:Temporary failure in name resolution
connect:errno=11

wget github.com 
--2022-04-28 09:52:02--  http://github.com/
Resolving github.com (github.com)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘github.com’
```

I tried to wget website ip address:

```
wget 140.82.113.3
--2022-04-28 10:01:13--  http://140.82.113.3/
Connecting to 140.82.113.3:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://140.82.113.3/ [following]
--2022-04-28 10:01:13--  https://140.82.113.3/
Connecting to 140.82.113.3:443... connected.
The certificate's owner does not match hostname ‘140.82.113.3’
```

if I browse the ip address, I have got a warning message saying the cert is wrong, if I try to pass it over (accept risk), there is no way to access website.

nothing blocking in my hosts file:

```
cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   zavata.circus.net   zavata
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Everything look fine in my routing table (192.168.0.1 beeing my default gw, a 4g router)

```
route -n 

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp1s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp1s0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp1s0
```

Many thanx folks !!

Comment: what is the content of `/etc/resolv.conf` ?

Comment: The obvious suggestion is that your ISP is blocking DNS queries. This is consistent with tlslookup working but dig and nslookup failing. You say that this is a 4g router. It might be that you are stuck behind "carrier grade nat". You can try downloading using the `--no-check-certificate` argument to `wget` **after** you have read the manual.

Comment: Are you using `linux` (the banner in dig suggests you are), and if so can you edit `/etc/systemd/resolv.conf` to change `#DNSOverTLS=no` to `DNSOverTLS=yes` (i.e. delete the `#` and change `no` to `yes`).  then restart the resolver (simplest is a reboot, or else try `systemctl restart NetworkManager`) You should then be able to use 127.0.0.53 as the nameserver to query.

Comment: nb. The result you get from tlsnslookup in the stand-alone command is 140.82.113.4, but when you use the output you get 140.82.114.3 - a typo perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem comes from the operator. As soon as I change of FAI/operator, I can access github.com without any issue. I just made an entry in my hosts file to access the website when connected to the faulty FAI.

Comment: @icarus: a whois of both addresses show that 140.82.112.0/20 belongs to github.com.